# How can I get control of the generation process of config.xml file for a jenkins job?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm new to Jenkins and now I'm supposed to develop a jenkins plugin. In the plugin will create a new job type, and generate the configuration page of this job type. I've finish this one by extending the class  "hudson.model.Project" ;

For now, when I click "save", nothing goes into the configuration file(config.xml) of the new job. I want to get control of the configuration file's generation process in order to set default builders and parameters of the certain builder for each job.

Anyone could help in explain how could I make it with Jenkings Plugin (especially by extending hudson.model.Project)? Or anyone can tell me which part of the src code or any documentation I should read in order to get some knowledge of it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a plugin to create new jenkins jobs programatically  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin